# Android count occurences in List<Pair<Long, Pair<Integer, Integer>>> by field

Tags: java, android

I want to count into `someList` all repeating longs (obj.first) in list.

Here are declarations:

```
private static List<Pair<Long, Pair<Integer, Integer>>> xyOffset = new ArrayList<>();
private static List<Integer> someList = new ArrayList<>();
private static int counter = 0;
private static long oldGid;
```

Here is what I have done regarding this counting, but it does not work because I have no idea how to do that and this is the question of this post how to solve that to have `someList` with output as written at the bottom of this post:

```
        for (Pair<Long, Pair<Integer, Integer>> obj : xyOffset) {
            counter++;
            if (oldGid == obj.first) {

            } else {
                someList.add(counter);
                counter = 0;
            }
            oldGid = obj.first;
        }
```

`xyOffset` is sorted ascending by .first like that: `Collections.sort(xyOffset, ComparatorCompat.comparing(o -> o.first));`.

Here is  an example of data.

**Input** of `xyOffset`:

[Pair{2 Pair{924 181}}, Pair{2 Pair{1078 181}}, Pair{2 Pair{1694 543}}, Pair{3 Pair{154 181}}, Pair{4 Pair{770 543}}, Pair{21 Pair{308 724}}, Pair{21 Pair{462 543}}]

and as an **output** I want `someList` to have:

[3, 1, 1, 2]

Explanation of expected output:

- 3 occurrences of 2,
- 1 occurrence of 3,
- 1 occurrence of 4,
- 2 occurrences of 21.

PS: I hope my post is understandable.

Comment: Is your code working as expected or do you have any issues? What is your question?

Comment: As I said my code does not work. I want to get a list as I wrote based on this example input

Comment: How does the pair class look like? Is it a custom class or are you using some library? If yes which library?

Comment: this Pair class comes from androidx.core.util

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Stream over your list and map each pair to `first`
- create a map by grouping by identity and mapping to frequency

and finaly get the values of the map

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Pair<Long, Pair<Integer, Integer>>> xyOffset = List.of(
            Pair.create(2L, Pair.create(924, 181)),
            Pair.create(2L, Pair.create(1078, 181)),
            Pair.create(2L, Pair.create(1694, 543)),
            Pair.create(3L, Pair.create(154, 181)),
            Pair.create(4L, Pair.create(770, 543)),
            Pair.create(21L, Pair.create(308, 724)),
            Pair.create(21L, Pair.create(462, 543)));
    
    List<Long> result = new ArrayList<>(xyOffset.stream()
                                                 .map(p -> p.first)
                                                 .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),Collectors.counting()))
                                                 .values());

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

If you want a non stream approach: Create an intermediate map, iterate over your input list and update your map using `first` as key and frequency as value

```
Map<Long,Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

for (Pair<Long, Pair<Integer, Integer>> pair : xyOffset) {
    map.merge(pair.first, 1, (x, y) -> x + y);
}

List<Long> result2 = new ArrayList<>(map.values());
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. Tommorow I will test it and if this solution works then I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with this code:

```
    for (Pair<Long, Pair<Integer, Integer>> obj : xyOffset) {
        counter++;
        if (oldGid == obj.first) {

        } else {
            someList.add(counter);
            counter = 0;
        }
        oldGid = obj.first;
    }
```

1. The first time through the loop, `oldGid` will not be equal to `obj.first` because it is never initialized and so `oldGid` will have the value of zero. This will result in an entry added to `someList` with the value of 1. The second element added to `someList` have the wrong count as well due to this same problem. To fix this problem you need to skip the `if` statement the first time through the loop and simply set `oldGid = obj.first`. You can remember if it is the first time through the loop by using a `boolean` variable.
2. You increment `counter` at the beginning of the loop. Since you are adding the elements to `someList` when you detect a change in the value of `obj.first`, you need to make sure that you increment the `counter` variable only AFTER you add the element to `someList`.
3. Since you only add an element to `someList` when you detect a change in the value of `obj.first`, you will fail to add the last element to `someList` because the `for` loop will simply complete. So you need to add code to add the last element to `someList` after the `for` loop ends.

Comment: Tkank you for informations!